# Totient minimal value for semiprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, totient-function

I have two question concerning Euler Totient of semiprimes.

*First question* : given $N=p_1 * p_2$ and $M=p_3*p_4$ where $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are prime numbers greater than 5; and $M>N$ this means that also $\phi(M)>\phi(N)$ ?

*Second question* : what is the minimum value that $\phi(M)$ can have ? I know that Mr. Sierpinski estimated the minimum value involving the Eulero-Mascheroni constant, but do we have a better "low bound" estimationf for the Euler Totient of a semiprime like $M$ ?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, the answer is no. You can have $M>N$ and $\varphi(M)<\varphi(N)$.

For example take $M=7\cdot 131=917$. Then $\varphi(M)=6\cdot 130=780$.

And take $N=29\cdot 31=899$. Then $\varphi(N)=28\cdot 30 =840$.

Comment: The smallest examples are $N = 7 \cdot 13$, $M=5 \cdot 19$, which give $\varphi(M)=\varphi(N)$, and $N = 7 \cdot 29$, $M=5 \cdot 41$, which give $\varphi(M)<\varphi(N)$